# Get number of lines added/edited/deleted per changeset in Visual Studio 2013+

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Our dev. team needs to implement auditing for our work; is there a way to get the number of lines added, edited and deleted per changeset?

The idea is that, per work/task/PBI item that a changeset is associated with we would like to get the number of lines affected.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `TFS Build` feature you can use a standard report to view the code churn [Build Quality Indicators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380683.aspx). Otherwise you can check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jampick/archive/2010/07/06/tfs-2010-code-churn-report-getting-additional-detail.aspx) guide of how to get that information.

Comment: OK, thank you I will check this out and mark as answer if/when I get this working by tomorrow.

Comment: Np, I have updated the post with a link to the Build Quality Indicators. Good luck.

Comment: I couldn't get this work; I will need to go about it another way :(